# Inverse of a random variable where \Omega =[0,1]

Tags: probability-distributions

If I have a random variable 
$$ X:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\quad \text{so that} \quad
 X(w)=\min\{w,1-w\} , \quad \text{ where } w \in [0,1]$$
The question is to find the inverse of the random variable ,which is as follows :
$$ X^{-1}(]-\infty,x]=`\phi\quad \text{ if } x<0
$$
$$ [0,x]\bigcup[1-x,1] \quad\text {if}  0<=x<=1/2
$$
$$ [0,1] \quad\text     {if}  x>=1/2 $$ `

Does someone know how did he calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

$X(w) > x$ iff $w > x$ and $1-w > x$ iff $w > x$ and $w < 1-x$. If $x \geq 1-x$ or $x  \geq \frac  1 2$ then this is impossible. If $x \in [0,\frac 1 2]$ this is equivalent to $x <w <1- x$. Now just take the complement in $[0,1]$ to get the inverse image of $(-\infty, x]$.

Comment: i corrected the second case